# How does a local printer driver find a network printer?

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, printing

(I have searched Google for days on this. No luck. Trade secret? )

I have a laptop with a printer self-installed (Canon MF4500w Series). The laptop communicates through air to the printer. The printer itself is connected directly to the router and no static ip address is used for the printer. The router assigns the ip address to the printer.

In my laptop, their is NO registry entry for the printer in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports

However, there is a port entry for Canon MFNP Port:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Canon MFNP Port\Ports

of CNMFNP_001E8FB0726C
```

This registry entry shows:

```
IPFixed        REG_DWORD    0x000000000 (0)
PrinterPort    REG-DWORD    0x0000238c (9100)
Protocol       REG_DWORD    0x00000001 (1)
TargetAddress  REG_DWORD    0x390b000a (957022218)
TargetMAC      REG_SZ       00-1E-8F-B0-72-6C
TargetPort     REG_DWORD    0x0000021a2 (8610)
```

My guess is that the printer driver itself is equipped with the ability to search for the networked printer by information in the registry.

Is there a windows function (ideally in C#) that can perform this same function and return the current IP address of a printer given something in this registry entry?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it unlikely that there is a universal solution; there's no obvious reason why Windows would care what the IP address of the printer is, even assuming it has one.  You would need to deal with each type of print monitor separately.  In this case, you've got the MAC, so perhaps there's a way to do a reverse lookup on that?

Comment: @HarryJohnston If I go into Windows Printers --> Ports -->Configure Port. Windows does report the ip address of 10.0.11.57. Can this be replicated in code?

Comment: I *think* that is being displayed by the third-party print monitor.  But I may be wrong, hopefully an expert can help out here.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The best I can come up with is using the LocalPrintServer() to get the queue dirver name. Then manually creating a xml file to match the possible MAC of the printer to the driver. Then arp -a can match the MAC to the IP address. Anybody have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a newbie, I'd like to post my findings in the hope someone who knows more then me can improve this answer. (I hope this is in the spirit of SO).

The short answer to the question is: Only the printer driver knows how to reach its target device.

The long answer:

1. Printing must be one of the weakest most non-standardized parts of the Windows operating system.
2. The win32_ managment system is based on the assumption of standarized entries in the windows registry, which simply does not occur for third party printer applications. Therefore, the win32_ management system can only be used when it is already known how the third party printer installed itself.
3. Once it is known how the third party printer installed itself, then a specific reader for the registry can be easily made to find the information used by the third party printer. But even with this information, it could be a blind rabbit hole since ultimately it is the printer driver that has the specific knowledge on what to do with this information.
4. As far as I can tell, there is no standardization among printer drivers with perhaps the lone exception of the Printer Command Language, more commonly referred to as PCL.
5. I am sure that windows has the PCL embedded somewhere in one of its API's, but it does not seem readily available through the .NET system. It would also require knowing the specific syntax needed for the commands, again information that I do not (as yet) know. My brief survey of this also shows it would require knowing the IP address of the printer, which is another rabbit hole.
6. Perhaps excepting for the MAC address of the printer, there are apparently no constants in the system:
   6.1. The "Ip Addresses" windows displays are only aliases for the actual IP Address. I suspect the reason here is that a printer can be dynamically reassinged an IP Address at turn-on by the router. So the software can "follow" the new IP address and assign that IPAddress to the alias Ip Address which stays constant for the port descriptions.
   6.2  The Printer Queue (the one displayed in Windows Printers and Devices) can be arbitrarily renamed by the user. It is not a constant.
   6.3  The "Port Name" can be arbitrarily renamed by the user.
   6.4  A given printer driver can be used multiple times for different devices. There is a one-to-many relationship here. Clearly the device driver must understand the registry locations and entries established when the device was installed. (Again, third party information.)
   6.5  Even the MAC for a device can be spoofed at the router level--so not even this is a constant.
7. Since ultimately, everything can be arbitrarily set and only the third party printer driver understands where and how to use the registry information, the simplest solution I can think of is to:
   7.1 Tag the printer que (the one in windows printers and devices) with the MAC of the target device.
   7.2 Do not change the MAC of the target device.
   7.3 Use arp -a (or some variant of it) to obtain the actual IP addresses of the devices at run-time. This would provide the actual mapping of the IP address to the device.

I hope an expert will correct this answer! Thanks.

Comment: re 5.: PCL is a de-facto standard for talking to a printer, but not the only one; there are still printers that use Postscript instead, and not so many years ago there were lots of other alternatives.  Many printers didn't use any standard, each brand or even each model had a unique language.  The upshot is that the Windows API, by design, doesn't use PCL or any other particular printer language.